# About the main theorem of CM for elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

The classical main theorem of CM by Shimura states, among other things, that:

Consider a quadratic imaginary $K/\mathbb Q$ and an elliptic curve $E= \mathbb C / \Lambda$ with CM s.t. $End(E)\otimes \mathbb Q =K$. Consider $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb C)$ and an idèle $s$ such that $[s,K]= \sigma_{\vert K^{ab}}$. Then, $E^\sigma \cong \mathbb C / s^{-1}\Lambda$.

In particular, the $\sigma$ in the statement necessarily fixes $K$ by the definition of the reciprocity map. Very roughly, this result tells you that the conjugates under $Gal(\bar{\mathbb Q}/K)$ of a CM elliptic curve are determined by the action of the idèles of $K$. The subtle point is that this holds for all elliptic curves with CM in $K$ at the same time.

Suppose you are now given $\sigma \in Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$, not necessarily fixing $K$. I would like to know if it is possible to study the conjugates of $E$ by means of idèles in the same fashion. That is: is there an analog of the main theorem of CM for automorphisms $\sigma \in Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ and idèles of $\mathbb Q$?

Thank you!